# Access to other components variables in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-three-fiber

I'm using react three fiber and i have two components
one to make a box and the other is to make an array of this box

here's how they look like, the platform component:

```
export function Plat() {

    const [active, setActive] = useState(0)
    const { scale } = useSpring({ scale: active ? 1 : 0.4 })
    const [mat] = useState(() => new THREE.TextureLoader().load('/matcap.png'))

    function Shape(props) {
        return (
            <animated.mesh {...props} scale={scale} onPointerOver={() => setActive(Number(!active))} >
                <RoundedBox args={[60,20,60]} radius={4} smoothness={4} position={[0, -10, 0]} dispose={null} >
                    <meshMatcapMaterial matcap={mat} />
                </RoundedBox>
            </animated.mesh>
        );
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        (function() {
            setActive((1))
        })();
    },[]);
  
    return (
        <Shape />   
    )
}
```

and the component that makes an array of this platform:

```
import {Plat} from './Plat'

export default function Boxes() {

    function MyShape(props) {
      return (
          <mesh {...props} >
              <Plat />
          </mesh>
      );
    }

    const [shapes, setShapes] = useState([<MyShape key={0} position={[100, 100, 100]} />, <MyShape key={1} position={[120, 120, 120]} />, <MyShape key={2} position={[130, 130, 130]} />]);
  
    return (
      <group >
        {[...shapes]}
      </group>
    )

  }
```

(I have more than 3 elements in the array)
I wanna know if there's a way to access the variables inside each of the array's platform components
how would I do something like this:

console.log(shapes[2].position) or change the position of this specific shape in the array
or this
shapes[1].setActive(1)

is it even possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Few pointer

- Avoid [nesting functional](https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/your-first-component#nesting-and-organizing-components) components

Plat
Shape // declare this outside and pass it the params from parent

- If you need to change the position of the children, consider creating a array with the information you need to change

  ```
    const [shapes, setShapes] = useState<>([{ key: 1, position: { x: 5, y: 10 } }])

    const changeShapePostions = (key) => {
        setShapes(items => {

           return items.map(shape => {

             if (shape.id === key) {
                return { ...shape, position: { x: updatedX, y: updated: y} }
             } else {
                return shape
             }

          }

        }
    }


      const setActive = (key) => {
         setShapes(items => {

           return items.map(shape => {

             if (shape.id === key) {
                return { ...shape, isActive: true }
             } else {
                return shape
             }

          }

        }
  }


  return (
      <group >
        {
          shapes.map(shape => {
              return (<MyShape key={shape.key} position={shape.position} setActive={setActive} />)
          }
        }
      </group>
    )
  ```

you can check standard practices on [working with arrays](https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/updating-arrays-in-state#updating-objects-inside-arrays)

Hope it helps in some ways